# How can i design cover image in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am new to ionic design. How can i design cover image and it should shrinked.

reference image [image]

Comment: just use a class as in normal css and use it. It has nothing to do ionic design. Just your normal design.

Comment: okay. I will try. can you please provide any examples?